# Access variable from code behind via javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, json

I have the following code that I want to return to a variable "t" in javascript:

Code behind:

```
Public Shared Function GetSomeText() As String
  Dim result = "This is from code behind"
  Return result
End Function
```

Caller variable in javascript:

```
//This is not working like that, I think
    var t = GetSomeText();
```

So, how can I make variable "t" get the "result" from Function GetSomeText from code-behind?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, that's _Javascript_, not jQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this -- assuming that this a public method on the page.  This will call the method GetSomeText() on the page class and then do a Response.Write() of the data to the page as it's being rendered.  The result should end up between the single quotes in your javascript.

```
 var t = '<%= GetSomeText() %>';
```

Comment: @SLaks  -- I would say that it depends on what the method returns.  If the text is user-generated, then it certainly needs to be escaped properly.  If the program is generating text under the programmer's control then it probably isn't.  Certainly encoding any user-generated data is required.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the string to a Javascript variable in server-side code, like this: (In a `<script>` block in the ASPX page)

```
var t = "<%= GetSomeText() %>";
```

Note that you *must* correctly escape it, like this: (Or using the [AntiXSS Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en)

```
public static void QuoteString(this string value, StringBuilder b) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return "";

    var b = new StringBuilder();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
        char c = value[i];

        // Append the unhandled characters (that do not require special treament)
        // to the string builder when special characters are detected.
        if (c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == '\"' || c == '\'' || c == '<' || c == '>' ||
            c == '\\' || c == '\n' || c == '\b' || c == '\f' || c < ' ') {
            if (b == null) {
                b = new StringBuilder(value.Length + 5);
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
            }

            startIndex = i + 1;
            count = 0;
        }

        switch (c) {
            case '\r':
                b.Append("\\r");
                break;
            case '\t':
                b.Append("\\t");
                break;
            case '\"':
                b.Append("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                b.Append("\\\\");
                break;
            case '\n':
                b.Append("\\n");
                break;
            case '\b':
                b.Append("\\b");
                break;
            case '\f':
                b.Append("\\f");
                break;
            case '\'':
            case '>':
            case '<':
                AppendCharAsUnicode(b, c);
                break;
            default:
                if (c < ' ') {
                    AppendCharAsUnicode(b, c);
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    if (b == null) {
        b.Append(value);
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
    }

    return b.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nice one. But it's a little long.

Comment: Worked for me, was trying to pass a directory path. This is the only way to do it.

AppendCharAsUnicode method found here:
http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/Orcas/RTM/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptString@cs/1/JavaScriptString@cs