# Wrong data showing in Plotly.js graph

Tags: javascript, asp.net, plotly

I'm trying to use data from my code behind to display a plot.ly graph on my webpage. Here is the code for the html:

```
 <div id="mydiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <script> 
        var fi = '<%= fi %>';

        //define different lines on the graph
        var freeze = {
            x: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
            y: fi,
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            name: 'Sum FI'
        };

        var data = [freeze];

        var layout = {
            title: 'Freeze and Thaw Indexes',
            xaxis: {
                title: 'Date'
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: 'Sum'
            }
        };

        Plotly.newPlot('mydiv', data, layout);
    </script>
</div>
```

If I add an alert(fi) to the page, I see that

```
fi= [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

which is exactly what it should be. However, the graph that is showing up is as if

```
fi=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

or, in other words, the exact same as what I set for my x. Since I know I'm getting the correct variable from the code behind because when I check it with an alert, it's exactly what it's supposed to be, I really don't know why the graph is completely different. If anyone has any thoughts as to how to fix this, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I tried replicating the issue on code pen with the hard coded y values, but I cannot reproduce the error.  It looks like the error might be with your fi array.  Try hard coding the array and see if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without apostrophes?

```
var fi = <%= fi %>;
```

Comment: Exactly the problem, thanks so much. Do you know why that would cause a problem? I'm only curious because this post had the apostrophes, so I included them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714546/access-variable-from-code-behind-via-javascript

Comment: This is another type of data. You have to pass number array to javascript, but you pass a string that looks like an array.